# How to solve 400 bad request error in my nuxt-strapi app?

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi, nuxt-auth

I was working on a nuxt-strapi app 3 month ago. After 3 month delay, I decided to continue the project. In my app I have an **Authentication** system that uses [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/). The registration process works fine before. But now, it shows me errors in console. First this is the template part of **register** page:

> register.vue template:

```html
<v-form
    v-if="!success"
    v-model="valid"
    lazy-validation
    ref="form"
    class="my-form py-10"
    >
    <v-container>
        <v-row
        justify="center"
        >
        <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="9"
            align-self="center"
        >
            <v-text-field
            v-model="username"
            :rules="nameRules"
            label="نام کاربری"
            required
            class="emailClass"
            color="accent darken-4"
            >
            </v-text-field>
        </v-col>

        <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="9"
            align-self="center"
        >
            <v-text-field
            v-model="password"
            :rules="passRules"
            type="password"
            label="رمز عبور"
            color="accent darken-4"
            required
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>

        <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="9"
            align-self="center"
        >
            <v-text-field
            v-model="passwordRepeat"
            :rules="passwordRepeatRules"
            type="password"
            label="تکرار رمز عبور"
            color="accent darken-4"
            required
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>

        <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="9"
            align-self="center"
        >
            <v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            :rules="emailRules"
            label="آدرس ایمیل"
            color="accent darken-4"
            class="emailClass"
            required
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        </v-row>

        <v-row
        align="center"
        justify="center"
        >
                <v-btn
                color="accent lighten-5"
                class="regBtn mx-auto my-6 py-8"
                x-large
                elevation="8"
                @click="register"
                >
                ثبت نام
                </v-btn>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>

</v-form>
```

And this is the `register` method in script part:

> register.vue script:

```js
async register() {

    if( this.$refs.form.validate() ) {
        try {
            this.$axios.setToken(false);
            await this.$axios.post("/auth/local/register", {
            username: this.username,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
            });
        } catch (e) {

          console.log(e);
        } // end of try-catch
    } else {
        console.log("some errors)
    }

}, // end of register method
```

I generally followed [this tutorial](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-authentication-in-nuxt-js) for building the **Authentication system** and the version of my nuxt is `2.15.8`. The version of my strapi is `3.6.8` and node version is `14.15.1`.

Finally these are two images of the error occurred in the console:

> img1:
> [image: the image of console error]

> img2:
> [image: the image of console error]

I could not understand what is the **reason** of this error. I need some help to know what happened in my app after 3 month. Because I did not changed anything from that time!

Also something that is strange for me is that the information of the registered user is added in my `strapi Users collection type` (means in my database), but the result of post request is an error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching for the reason of that error, I finally found that what the problem is. In my "strapi" admin panel, I turned off the **Enable email confirmation** part shown in the image below:

[image: image of strapi admin panel]

After that, the registration and login process works fine. Also, if someone wants that **"Enable email confirmation"** be turned on, he/she must be confident about sending verification email to the registered user.

Because I was working on my local PC and localhost, I turned it off. But for keeping that on, I think [this guide](https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-send-email-confirmation-after-register/11888) could be helpful.